# Ember.JS concurrency task, perform() is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js, task, ember-concurrency

I was trying to convert a function over to a task. Here is the original code:

Call:

```
this.socketConnect(endpoint, token);
```

Function:

```
socketConnect = async (token, endpoint) => {
        this.socket = new WebSocket(endpoint + '?auth=' + token);

        this.socket.addEventListener('open', () => {
                this.socket.addEventListener('message', event => this.handleMessage(event));

                this.socket.addEventListener('close', event => this.retryConnection(event, endpoint));

        });
    }
```

I've been following structure on implementing Ember tasks. It all compiles with no issue, however when it gets called, it outputs that this.socketConnect(...) is not a function. Before hand I didn't have the return below and it output that this.socketConnect wasn't a function. Here is my current code for a task.

Import:

```
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';
```

Call:

```
this.socketConnect(endpoint, authToken).perform();
```

Function:

```
@task *socketConnect(endpoint, token) {
        yield async () => {
            this.socket = new WebSocket(endpoint + '?auth=' + token);
            this.socket.addEventListener('open', () => {
                this.socket.addEventListener('message', event => this.handleMessage(event));

                this.socket.addEventListener('close', event => this.retryConnection(event, endpoint));
            });

            return;
        };

    }
```

New to this, so I'm guessing there's something small I'm missing. It matches other uses. Also if anyone could help on the benefits of switching a websocket generation function to a task? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `@task` decorator isn't part of the official `ember-concurency` package yet. The official version lives in [ember-concurrency-decorators](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency-decorators) for now.  You'll need to 
`ember install ember-concurrency-decorators`

and then you can do

`import { task } from 'ember-concurrency-decorators';`

To use it.

Alternatively you can use a [different syntax](https://github.com/machty/ember-concurrency-decorators#do-i-need-this-addon) if you don't want another dependency.

```
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

class Foo {
  @(task(function*() {
    // ...
  }).restartable())
  doStuff;

  executeTheTask() {
    this.doStuff.perform();
  }
}
```

To call the task the syntax is:
`this.socketConnect.perform(endpoint, authToken);`

As you're not calling socketConnect directly, you want to call the method that ember concurrency generates for you.

Comment: When I import ember-concurrency-decorators it just says that this.socketConnect is not a function.

Comment: Ah, I think I see where that is happening. I added some details, but you'll want to call ` this.socketConnect.perform(endpoint, authToken);` with the arguments passed to perform not to socketConnect.

Comment: I've also never seen you're `yield async` structure inside of a task. It looks like it should work, but it's not what I normally see so that may be part of the problem as well.